# What to do when I can't directly access Git server?

Tags: git

To access a certain Git server, I need to ssh to a remote Linux workstation that only it can access the git server.

What can I do if I want to use the Git from my local Linux workstation?

Comment: This doesn't seem like a technical problem, but an operational one. If the Git server is only accessible from specific workstations, there is a very good chance that you're not supposed to try to work around that by copying the repository, and doing so anyway is very likely to be a breach of contract. Check *very* carefully before continuing.

Comment: And if it turns out I'm wrong and the responsible people are okay with you having the repository on your local workstation, then the answer should be "ask your sysadmin for access to the server", *still* don't try to do it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `ssh` tunnel through your Linux work station. As explained [here](http://www.revsys.com/writings/quicktips/ssh-tunnel.html)

```
ssh -f user@personal-server.com -L 2000:personal-server.com:25 -N
```

> The -f tells ssh to go into the background just before it executes the command. This is followed by the username and server you are logging into. The -L 2000:personal-server.com:25 is in the form of -L local-port:host:remote-port. Finally the -N instructs OpenSSH to not execute a command on the remote system.